# Get rid of .ds_store in 10.11+

Tags: macos

I'm a programmer and I need to display hidden files on my Mac, and, of course, those damn .ds_store files turns my life into a living hell. For a long time I have been using https://asepsis.binaryage.com/, but it is no longer in active development due to new OS X restrictions.

Is there an updated answer to the question about an out of the box solution to get rid of these little bastards?

Also, I'm aware that I can use asepsis in 10.11 with a little tweak but this is not an optimal solution.